# Do plants refix some of the carbon dioxide in the Calvin cycle that they produce through cellular respiration?

Tags: photosynthesis, cellular-respiration

Plants do cellular respiration and release CO<sub>2</sub> into the air, but does the plant also use some of this CO<sub>2</sub> to do the Calvin cycle? Or does all the CO<sub>2</sub> required for the Calvin cycle come in through the stomata?

Answer (score 1):

Gases like CO<sub>2</sub> move quite freely in biological systems, approximating the [laws of diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion) (note: there are of course some exceptions, especially underwater, as well as with proteins that assist in bulk transport of CO<sub>2</sub> like hemoglobin).

If you were to measure the *net* amount of CO<sub>2</sub> coming into the stomata, it would indeed approximate the *net* CO<sub>2</sub> use by the plant. **From this, you could make a claim like "the CO<sub>2</sub> a plant needs comes in through the stomata": this is true for the *net*, and that's usually what's most important to a biologist.**

However, if you want to get picky about what really happens at a molecular level, the *flux* of CO<sub>2</sub> coming through the stomata is not the same as the *net*: no one is keeping track of the individual gas molecules, they just float around back and forth. The only reason there is a net flow at all is due to a *concentration gradient*: because the plant uses some CO<sub>2</sub>, there is less inside than outside. When molecules move around randomly, that means that a few more end up coming inside than are leaving. When we talk about net diffusion we are talking about the averages of many many molecules over time.

Included in that random motion are not just the CO<sub>2</sub> molecules present inside and outside the plant, but also those that the plant is producing through cellular respiration. **By chance, certainly, some of these molecules could end up back in the Calvin cycle.** Some could even exit through the stomata and come back in (my intuition is that this is quite improbable for an individual molecule but I haven't done the math...the important concept is that it's all one "pool").

If you really wanted to know, you could set up a Monte Carlo simulation (or use differential equations) and calculate probabilities of all sorts of event sequences for individual molecules. You could also tilt the scales a bit if you, say, put the equivalent of a 'plastic bag' over a leaf, either physically or in a model: if there's a limited amount of CO<sub>2</sub> in the "outside" space it would be much more likely for individual molecules to be "reused".

From a biologists' perspective, though, and especially for ubiquitous, freely moving molecules like CO<sub>2</sub>, it's usually only important to think about *net* flow.

Comment: Great answer — thanks for fixing the egregious mistake I introduced into the title!

Comment: @tyersome Haha no problem. Shh don't tell anyone but I edited my answer before the time edits register to fix the place I referred to CO2 as an "ion" - maybe a bit too much neuroscience for me. Happens to us all sometimes :)